# unabe to Reload data in tableview via userdefault

Tags: swift, xcode8

I am a newbie and learning  ios programming. I have made a custom table view cell. I am trying to append data in it via user defaults but its not storing the data, every time i go back the app refreshes  making the table view blank screen.

```
// data sent from here


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: AnyObject) {



        performSegue(withIdentifier: "move", sender: nil)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destination = segue.destination as? secondviewcontroller



        destination?.list.append(textfield.text!)

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(destination?.list, forKey: "listarray")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    }
}


// here i want to retreive
class secondviewcontroller: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    var list = ["fahad","Ali","tahir"]

   var abc = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblView.dataSource  = self;
    tblView.delegate = self;


    let storedarray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "listarray")

    print("hi\(storedarray)")
}



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     tblView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    tblView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func backbtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

import UIKit

class secondviewcontroller: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
var list = ["fahad","Ali","tahir"]
```

var abc = ""

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblView.dataSource  = self;
    tblView.delegate = self;



}



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     tblView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    let storedarray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "listarray")

    print("hi\(storedarray)")
    tblView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func backbtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

extension secondviewcontroller : UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate{

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print (list)
    return list.count;
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell;
    cell.textlabel.text = list[indexPath.row];


    return cell;


}
```

}

```
// my custom table view
import UIKit

class   TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textlabel: UILabel!   
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

[My UI storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44xnL.png)[getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjNqB.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. you must subclass the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods and implement the required methods for it to display the data in your custom view. 
   refer to this: http://clean-swift.com/refactoring-table-view-data-source-and-delegate-methods/

   2. try adding the code for stored array into the viewwillappear method..

Comment: Think its to do with the way you configured your second view controller.. i ran the same code and it works here.

Comment: check the new answer

Comment: let me know if it works and if so upvote the answer for others to see as well

Answer (score 0):

These lines recreates the same list with an new element without considering the saved items:

```
    destination?.list.append(textfield.text!)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(destination?.list, forKey: "listarray") 
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

You should instead:

```
let newEntry = textfield.text!
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if destination?.list.count == 3 {  //3 because you hardcoded 3 items in next controller
      destination?.list.append(newEntry) 
} else {
      let obj = defaults.object(forKey: "listarray") as? [String] ?? [String]()
      destination?.list = obj.append(newEntry)
}
defaults.set(destination?.list, forKey: "listarray")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: Its working the same way as my code was working.
["Fahad","ali","tahir"] ande when i am adding one the result is ["Fahad","ali","tahir","abc"]. When i go back and add another item the result is ["Fahad","ali","tahir","xyz"] not ["Fahad","ali","tahir","abc","xyz"].
Did you got my point what i am looking for? I really appreciate your  help

Comment: ahh.. that's because you are adding from the second view controller the list which is hard coded... i'd suggest you do the following:

Comment: edited the question "please refer to getting this error image"(
It  says "value of type any has no member to append")

Comment: again an error  it says  on this line "  destination?.list = obj.append(newEntry)" 

cannot assign the value of type() to [String]